# Instantaneous velocity is slope of displacement-time curve?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, displacement

I have a toss-up question that I'm not sure how to answer. Here it is (true or false):

> The instantaneous velocity at a particular time is the slope of the displacement-time curve at that position.

I know that this statement would be true if it said `position-time curve` because that would mean that the change in position is the displacement. However, as the statement currently stands, it is saying that instantaneous velocity is equal to the change in the displacement over time, which is the change in the change in position over time. Am I correct to say that?

But when I do an example of each, they both seem to work. Like this:

> displacement 1 at 1 second is 10 m from the starting position.
>
> displacement 2 at 2 seconds is 20 m from the starting position.
>
> The change in displacements is 10 m, and over 1 second. So the velocity over that time period is 10 m/s.

And the same with position:

> position 1 at 1 second is 10 m from the starting position.
>
> position 2 at 2 seconds is 20 m from the starting position.
>
> The change in position is 10 m, and over 1 second. So the velocity over that time period is 10 m/s.

I can't decide what makes sense here. Is the statement true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your position is in 3D space (which means your position vector must be defined), then there is no distinction between displacement and *change in* position.

$s=\boldsymbol{R_f-R_i}=\Delta\boldsymbol{R}$
, where $s$ is displacement and $R$ is position.

However, in $v = ds/dt$, $ds$ does not mean change in displacement but rather an infinitesimally small displacement (infinitesimally small change in position). Since $v=ds/dt$, so the instantaneous velocity is the gradient to the tangent of the curve at that particular point.

In my opinion I believe it's just an issue of wording. I don't think change in displacement means $ΔΔR$, but rather the actual displacement(change in position) that occurred during a time $ΔT$

Comment: It's in 1D (going in one direction). And I know what you said is true, but what about the change in displacement? Is that the same as the change in position? I know that displacement = change in position. But it just seems odd that change in displacement also = change in position.

Comment: In my opinion I believe it's just an issue of wording. I don't think change in displacement means $\Delta\Delta{R}$, but rather the actual displacement(change in position) that occurred during a time $\Delta{T}$

Comment: I agree. So if you picture a displacement-time curve, would you say that any tangent to that curve has slope that's instantaneous velocity? That's the real question and I think that's correct.

Comment: Yes, that is true, since $v = ds/dt$, so the instantaneous velocity is the gradient to the tangent of the curve at that particular point.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe you can incorporate these comments into your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Good idea. I've added a little explanation about the 3D space (which extends to 1D as well, simply by fixing the value of two of the three axes).

Answer (score 0):

final position−initial position=final displacement from origin−initial displacement from origin.no,change in displacement is not equal to change in position,displacement is equal to change in position.but we can also write displacement in terms of displacement as displacement=final displacement from origin(as final position)-initial displacement from origin(as initial position).we just take origin as our permanent initial position.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).